# PushWoosh how to send notification at local time let's say 12:30pm ?

Tags: localization, push-notification, localtime, pushwoosh

Trying to send pushed at the users local time, not to disturb them.

Need to send push notification at users local time.

The Notification are sent not often with status of their gameplay, I am very aware not to spam users.

```
Class Helper {
function pwCall( $action, $data = array() ) {
    $url = 'https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/' . $action;
    $json = json_encode( array( 'request' => $data ) );
    $res = helper::doPostRequest( $url, $json, 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    @json_decode( $res, true );
}


helper::pwCall( 'createMessage', array(
'application' => PW_APPLICATION,
'auth' => PW_AUTH,
'notifications' => array(
            array(
                'send_date' => 'now',
                'content' => array('en' => "..your turn to play.",
                                   'fr' => "..votre tour de jouer",
                                   ),
                'ios_badges' => $row->count,
                'devices' => array($pushToken),                        
                'data' => array( 'custom' => 'json data' )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Need to replace 'now' with 12:30pm or 13:30 ( military time )

Answer (score 2):

You should put (example):

```
send_date => "2014-04-01 12:30",
ignore_user_timezone => false
```

Make sure you schedule notification at least 24 hours in advance if you use Timezeones.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in order to send a notification according to your users' time zones, all you need is to add the following line in your request:

'ignore_user_timezone' => false,

Then, you can specify the preferred time in 'send_date' section with the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm".  Military time would work just fine.